# Insert Multiple Checkboxes values in SQL as individual entry

Tags: php, mysql

i have different check boxes as mentioned in below code, and this code is working fine at my end as it concatenate all selected values and insert in DB as "PHP,.NET,JavaScript" etc. but what i want is if i have selected 3 check boxes it should add three individual entries 1. PHP 2. JavaScript, 3. Java. any idea or concept would be appreciated.

```
    <html>  
    <body>  
       <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
       <div style="width:200px;border-radius:6px;margin:0px auto">  
    <table border="1">  
       <tr>  
          <td colspan="2">Select Technolgy:</td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td>PHP</td>  
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="PHP"></td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td>.Net</td>  
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value=".Net"></td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td>Java</td>  
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="Java"></td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td>Javascript</td>  
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="javascript"></td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub"></td>  
       </tr>  
    </table>  
    </div>  
    </form>  
    <?php  
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))  
    {  
    $host="localhost";//host name  
    $username="root"; //database username  
    $word="";//database word  
    $db_name="dbtask";//database name  
    $tbl_name="new"; //table name  
    $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$word","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");//connection string  
    $checkbox1=$_POST['techno'];  
    $chk="";  
    foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
       {  
          $chk .= $chk1.",";  
       }  
    $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"insert into new(time) values ('$chk')");  
    if($in_ch==1)  
       {  
          echo'<script>alert("Inserted Successfully")</script>';  
       }  
    else  
       {  
          echo'<script>alert("Failed To Insert")</script>';  
       }  
    }  
    ?>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($checkbox1 as $key => $value)
        {
    $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"insert into new(time) values ('$value')");  

}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

please try with this

```
$checkbox1= $_POST["techno"]; 
foreach($checkbox1 as $key => $value){
     $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"insert into new(time) values ('$value')");  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to save as a comma separated list ?

```
implode(",", $_POST["techno[]"]);
```

Comment: this code is working with comma separated values, but i want to add individual entry in sql, like if i select 3 check boxes out of 4, it should enter 3 individual rows in sql.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your prompt response and ideas. mentioned code is working fine and i got the results as i want.

```
    <html>  
    <body>  
       <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
       <div style="width:200px;border-radius:6px;margin:0px auto">  
    <table border="1">  
       <tr>  
          <td colspan="2">Select Technolgy:</td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td>PHP</td>  
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="PHP"></td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td>.Net</td>  
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value=".Net"></td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td>Java</td>  
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="Java"></td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td>Javascript</td>  
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="techno[]" value="javascript"></td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub"></td>  
       </tr>  
    </table>  
    </div>  
    </form>  
    <?php  
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))  
    {  
    $host="localhost";//host name  
    $username="root"; //database username  
    $word="";//database word  
    $db_name="dbtask";//database name  
    $tbl_name="new"; //table name  
    $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$word","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");//connection string  
    $checkbox1=$_POST['techno'];  
    $chk=""; 

    foreach($checkbox1 as $key => $value)
            {
        $in_ch=mysqli_query($con,"insert into new(time) values ('$value')");  
    echo'<script>alert("Inserted")</script>';
    }


    }  
    ?>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```